# Jquery validator method not working if used multiple times in a form

Tags: jquery-validate

we are using a javascript form  where a enduser has to enter phonenumber and promo code apart from other details. All the fields in the form are mandatory.
I am using validator.add(method) to validate phonenumber  using regex.
Also using an another validator.add(method) to validate the promo code

But am able to use only one validator method. If am using multiple i.e., more than one, then the validation is not working.

Is the jquery validator method restricted to use only once in a form.
Please suggest me a solution for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use an OnSubmit function for the form and validate all the data there, you can also write several functions and use them in the main onsubmit function.